# Parce error at IF: Usage might be invalid MATLAB syntax

Tags: matlab

```
function [a] = Int_Force(x,x1,x2,u1,u2,rRep,rAli,rAtt)
r = x1-x2;
v = u1-u2;
if
    ((0 <= r) && (r < rRep));
    g = -1;
end 
if
    ((rRep <= r) && (r < rAli));
    g = 0;
end 
if
    (rAli <= r) && (r <= rAtt));
    g = 1;    
end    
a = (1/x-1)*Sum(g*r/norm(r)) + (1-mod(g)*(v/norm(v)));
end
```

Hi there, sorry I am new to Matlab this year and this is my first time using this website so apologies if I am being unclear. I am trying to create a function based on the interaction forces between moving vectors. I am experiencing errors with my 'if' statements, specifically the first 2 but not the last one, with the error message saying 'Parce error at IF: Usage might be invalid MATLAB syntax'. Does anyone know how I might fix this?
Cheers,
Dan.

Comment: Btw, indent by 4 spaces to properly format your code. Use back ticks for small inline code only. I did that, but I don't want to try to fix the rest of the indentation since I don't know Matlab, and don't want to mess with anything.

Comment: Thank you for your advice! :)

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the semi colons after the if statements. You can view valid if statement syntax [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/conditional-statements.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com)

```
function [a] = Int_Force(x,x1,x2,u1,u2,rRep,rAli,rAtt)
    r = x1-x2;
    v = u1-u2;
    if (0 <= r) && (r < rRep)
       g = -1;
    end 
    if (rRep <= r) && (r < rAli)
        g = 0;
    end 
    if (rAli <= r) && (r <= rAtt)
        g = 1;    
    end    
a = (1/x-1)*Sum(g*r/norm(r)) + (1-mod(g)*(v/norm(v)));
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: I have tried making those changes and sadly the code is still showing the same error. It actually wants me to re-add the semi colon for the first line of the if statement.